# Trying to link to external websites

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>
<a href = "www.google.com" target = "blank_">google</a>
</body>
<html>
```

What I get: www.mysite.com/www.google.com

What I want to get: www.google.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `http://` at the beginning of the URL.

```
<html>
<body>
 <a href = "http://www.google.com" target = "blank_">google</a>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you havent written http with the url,

try this

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```